# Plone Catalog Search - How can I query for objects by checking for numbers in a list field type it features?

Tags: plone

I have a dexterity content type, titled Supplier and it has a field titled supplierType and is defined in the Interface as a schema.List.  The list can contain values 1, 2, or 3, which correspond to a type name.  A Supplier can be more than one type (i.e. supplierType = [2,3])

Using a catalog, I want to query Suppliers whose supplierType list field contain one or more of these numbers I'm looking for.

So like I'm trying to look for a Supplier whose supplierType contains a 2 or 3.

Unfortunately, I am stuck on how a query would work.  I tried doing this:

```
supplierTypes = [1,2]
catalog = getToolByName(getSite(),"portal_catalog")

results = catalog(portal_type='gpcl.supplier.supplier',
                  supplierType={"query":supplierTypes,"operator":"or"})
```

Edit:
Testing to see if it worked by printing results, I don't get any suppliers back, but it doesn't crash.

What would the correct approach to querying supplier objects according to the criteria that one or more numbers I am looking for are in its supplierType list?

Also, technically I could just get the list of brains and then create a list, appending objects whose supplierType field contains a one or more numbers I am looking for, but I feel a query would be more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: have you created a new index in the Plone `portal_catalog`tool?

If not: your index type must be of `KeywordIndex` type (just name it `supplierType`). After that you simply need to query like this::

```
catalog(portal_type='gpcl.supplier.supplier', supplierType=[1, 3])
```

Refer to this: http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/searching_and_indexing/query.html

Also: are your sure that your portal type name is "gpcl.supplier.supplier"? Try manually surf the catalog to be sure of that (from "catalog" tab in ZMI catalog tool).

Comment: Thank you for your response.

I tried your line of code and unfortunately it returns with an empty list when I try printing it.

I can confirm the portal type name is "gpcl.gpcl.supplier" because I was using it for another query to return what types a supplier is.

I believe I have it indexed.  In profiles/default, I have a catalog.xml

In it I have:
    <object name="portal_catalog" meta_type="Plone Catalog Tool">

        <index name="supplierType">

            <indexed_attr value="isActive"

        </index>

    </object>

Comment: I also tried a different approach based on what you posted that unfortunately did not work:

catalog=getToolByName(getSite(),"portal_catalog")
results = catalog.searchResults({'portal_type':'gpcl.supplier.supplier','supplierType':[2,3]})


This also returned an empty list.

Comment: Sorry, I meant
<indexed_attr value="supplierType"/>

Comment: You don't need any indexer I think. Dexterity use storage in attributes. But if you simply run `catalog.searchResults({'portal_type':'gpcl.supplier.supplier'})` are you getting something?

Comment: Yes, I do get results back. In fact I can also target a single supplier, adding 'supplier_id':int(someID) and see a supplier's supplierType. (i.e. results[0]['supplierType']).

Comment: Also, I did check the catalog in the portal_catalog in the zcmi and clicking on one of the objects, the supplier type shows up as (in the case of 2 and 3) [2,3]

Comment: While in the zcmi, I noticed another index in the index contents that supplierType could found in, a list type called allowedRolesAndUsers which has ['Site Administrator', 'Manager', 'user:admin', 'Editor', 'Reader', 'Contributor'].  When I ran catalog.searchResults({'portal_type':'gpcl.supplier.supplier','allowedRolesAndUsers':['Site Administrator', 'Manager', 'user:admin', 'Editor', 'Reader', 'Contributor']}), I got back results.

Comment: Are you sure you created a KeywordIndex and not a FieldIndex?

Comment: Beside making sure using a KeywordIndex, I would also try `'supplierType': ['2', '3']`.

Comment: I found out that it wasn't a KeywordIndex after all.  At some point earlier I had made it a FieldType and then changed the catalog.xml to Keyword when you said to make sure it was that instead of FieldType.  I should've reinstalled the site instance.  Thank you for your answers.  I appreciate it and am now aware that I should use KeywordIndex for searching through the catalog.